# Extend inherited dockbar extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wrote two grid classes.
 
**BaseUsuarios.js:**

```
Ext.define('CRUDManantiales.view.grid.BaseUsuarios', {
     extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
     alias: 'widget.gridBaseUsuarios',
     title: 'Usuarios',
     initComponent: function(){
           ...
           this.callParent(arguments);
     }
});
```

And **FullUsuarios.js**

```
Ext.define('CRUDManantiales.view.grid.FullUsuarios', {
    extend: 'CRUDManantiales.view.grid.BaseUsuarios',
    alias: 'widget.gridFullUsuarios',
    title: 'Usuarios',
    initComponent: function(){
        ...
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

**BaseUsuarios.js** have a toolbar with 3 buttons, then **FullUsuarios.js** also. But i want add
some buttons in **FullUsuarios.js** toolbar.
How i can do ?.
Any idea ?.
Thanks !

Comment: I try and work:

` this.callParent(arguments); 
 this.getComponent('top-toolbar').add([
  ...
 ]);`
And works. But, is the correct way ?.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.define('MyBase', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        initComponent: function() {
            this.tbar = this.getTbarItems();
            this.callParent();
        },

        getTbarItems: function() {
            return [{
                text: 'Base'
            }]
        }
    });

    Ext.define('MySub', {
        extend: 'MyBase',

        getTbarItems: function() {
            var items = this.callParent();
            items.push({
                text: 'Sub'
            });
            // Could also insert etc
            return items;
        }
    });

    new MySub({
        renderTo: document.body
    });
});
```